# How can I have access to Glimpse MessageBroker outside of the ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

I am using Glimpse.Mvc5 (1.5.3) in a MVC5 project and I am making a custom tab. This tab needs information that will be logged from inside another project.
This project is not MVC, and is **referenced** by my MVC project.

I've managed to get the `MessageBroker` in two ways, but I don't think either of them are perfect:

#### By GetConfiguredMessageBroker

```
IMessageBroker broker = GlimpseConfiguration.GetConfiguredMessageBroker();
```

I first tried this, with success, but the method is marked as deprecated, so no deal

#### By GlimpseRuntime

```
GlimpseRuntime glimpseRuntime = HttpContext.Current.Application.Get("__GlimpseRuntime") as GlimpseRuntime;
IMessageBroker broker = glimpseRuntime.Configuration.MessageBroker;
```

Then I tried this, also with success, but two things bothered me: I had to add a reference to System.Web (for the `HttpContext`) which is really out of place in my project.
Using `"__GlimpseRuntime"` looks like something that could break in future releases.

I also realize this is breaking abstraction (a WEB tool showing up in my other project), so if a better answer doesn't use the `MessageBroker` altogether it is fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I'd recommend using the deprecated `GlimpseConfiguration.GetConfiguredMessageBroker()` technique you've found. (If it's working for you.)

The new version of Glimpse we are working on now handles messaging from other projects and processes as a first class citizen. Just be prepared to make some changes if/when you upgrade.

Comment: Just to be clear before I accept the answer, those are the only two workarounds available right now?

Comment: Baring running a customized version of Glimpse, yes.

Comment: @nikmd23 I have the same problem, so how can I watch to see when this appears in the new Glimpse? Do you know which version it will appear in or any API names etc I can keep an eye out for?

Comment: I'd recommend either my [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/nikmd23) or the [Glimpse blog](http://blog.getglimpse.com/).